# Is it possible to disable the initial data snapshot in Debezium?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

Currently, I am using Debezium for transferring data changes from our MySQL Binlog into Kafka, and then into BigQuery.

I use the distributed-mode configuration with `snapshot.mode=initial`. But unfortunately, the amount of data in our Mysql instances is too large because Debezium continuously read the Binlog from the beginning.

I am trying with `snapshot.mode=schema_only` and `auto.offset.reset=latest`. but there is still a spike in MySQL instance.

Is there any proper configuration for minimalize the heavy consumption of reading the Binlog?

Comment: `snapshot.mode` should definitely do the trick, is not the spike createaded only due to schema snapshotting?

Comment: What does auto.offset.reset=latest do?